# Create Plugins for Keynote

Tags: keynote, plugins

I'm interested in creating a plug-in for a keynote that shows a live web page (basically, an IFRAME). Keynote used to have this capability but no longer does. Is there any way to add this functionality to Keynote?

Two approaches that I can think of are:

1. An undocumented plug-in architecture. Does one exist?
2. A program that watches the keynote presentation and displays a floating window with the desired content? How would I pick up what is currently being displayed? Search for a QR code?